# Envío de logs con muchos espacios

Tags: servidor, debian

Os cuento el escenario. Tenemos electrónica de red, envío los logs a un equipo en particular (*Debian 8*). Aún con la rotación configurada, empezamos a tener problemas de espacio en este equipo, por lo que montamos un segundo nodo (también *Debian 8*).

En el nodo 1 mapeamos una carpeta del segundo, */logs*, y en el fichero *"/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf"* configuramos que todos los logs de la electrónica de red, fueran a parar a ese directorio del nodo 2.

Los logs están llegando bien a este segundo nodo, el problema que tenemos es que el nodo 1 envía una cantidad ingente de espacios al fichero. Hoy mismo lo he mirado, el fichero ha rotado a las 6 de la mañana y ya ocupaba 123 MB, cuando entras a él, el 99% del fichero son espacios, el 1% restante son los logs de los equipos.

En el nodo 1, el que recibe todos los logs por syslog de la electrónica de red, el fichero /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf está configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
filter f_local0 { 
    facility(local0) and not filter(f_debug);
};
log { 
    source(s_net); 
    filter(f_local); 
    destination(d_net); 
};
destination d_net { 
    file("/sondalogs/logscisco/cisco.txt"); 
};
```

Si haces un `df -h` en este equipo se puede ver el mapeo al nodo 2:
`10.3.220.220:/logs            538G    48G  462G  10% /sondalogs`

Estamos un poco perdidos sobre la causa del problema, ¿Formato de los logs?.

Comment: Hola Fran. Bienvenido. Has de poner algo de código que tengas que utilices para tratar esos `logs` y poder orientarnos un poco. Asi no está muy claro o es demasiado amplio. y que significa "Si abres el fichero con vi" ?

Comment: Gracias @lois6b ;)

Comment: No añadas informacion relevante en los comentarios, has de [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/34097/edit) tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿ Cuando los logs estaban en 1 solo equipo, estaba el mismo problema ? es decir, si quitas el mapeo de la unidad de red, ocurre lo mismo ?

Comment: No @Trauma, cuando los logs llegaban directamente al nodo 1 no ocurría.

Comment: Entonces es algún problema con el mapeo. Asumo que los logs son generados directamente por el servicio, y no a través de syslog ni nada parecido. Seguramente el que genera los logs hace un uso 'raro' de las funciones de escritura, que hacen que NFS se le vaya un poco la hoya. Si es así, difícil solución tendrá. NO, NO ES ESO, que me he confundido. Ni caso.

Answer (score 2):

Los síntomas que describes parecen indicar que el archivo de logs permanece abierto por `syslog-ng` después de haber sido rotado. Aunque el proceso de rotación mueva el contenido a otro archivo y trate de truncar el original, si el archivo sigue abierto `syslog-ng` seguirá escribiendo en la posición en la que le corresponde (de ahí el espacio vacío que ves al principio del archivo).

Debes hacer un `reload` de `syslog-ng` al final del proceso de rotación. Si estás rotando desde el nodo 2, debes trasladar la rotación al nodo 1.